# Should I change to scala to create a system with rewrite rules?

Tags: java, android, scala, architecture

I have some classes that I developed that I am using in a Android application. I have about 6-7 classes in that core, some of them are abstract classes with abstract methods. Those classes were created to provide a API to extend my Android Application.

Now I want to create an extensible system that accepts rewrite rules. Those rules are useful to replace some components at runtime. Imagine a system with mathematical operations where you see all the sums, multiplications, etc. Now you can zoom out and I want to simplify some operations dependending on the zoom level.

My system was built in java, but I belive that scala, with pattern matching, will simplify my problem. However, everytime I look at scala I see a lot of time I have to spend and a lot of headches configuring IDEs...

My classes are built to create structures like this one:

[image: an example of what I can build with my classes]

I want to be able to write rules that create a block that contains other blocks. Something like:

```
Integer Provider + Integer Provider -> Sum Provider
Sum Provider + Sum -> Sum Provider
```

Rules can be created by programmers. Any element of my structure can also be built by programmers. I don't know if scala simplifies this rule engine system, but I know that this engine, in java, can be boring to build (probly a lot of bugs will be created, I will forget some cases, etc).

Should I change all my system to scala? Or there is away to use only this feature of scala? Does it worth it?

PS: For more information on the structure please see this post at [User Experience](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/19069/how-to-display-a-flexible-and-expansible-structure-with-inputs-and-outputs-in-a).

Comment: Android support for Scala is still not good. If you intend to run on Android, I would not advise using Scala.

Comment: Yeah I know that... Although there were improvements made on the performance lately: http://scalandroid.blogspot.pt/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is easy to write such rules in Scala, and, in fact, there have been some questions on Stack Overflow related to rule rewriting systems in Scala. Also, there are some libraries that may help you with this, related to strategic programming and nlp, but I haven't used them, so I can't comment much.

Now, I don't know exactly where these classes are coming from. If you are parsing and building them, the parser combinator library can trivially handle it:

```
sealed trait Expr { def value: Int }
case class Number(value: Int) extends Expr
case class Sum(e1: Expr, e2: Expr) extends Expr { def value = e1.value + e2.value }

object Example extends scala.util.parsing.combinator.RegexParsers {
  def number: Parser[Expr] = """\d+""" ^^ (n => Number(n.toInt))
  def sum: Parser[Expr] = number ~ "+" ~ expr ^^ {
    case n ~ "+" ~ exp => Sum(n, exp)
  }
  def expr: Parser[Expr] = sum | number
}
```

If you have these classes in some other way and are applying simplifications, you could do it like this:

```
def simplify(expr: List[Expr]): Expr = expr match {
  case expr :: Nil => 
    List(expr) // no further simplification
  case (n1: NumberProvider) :: Plus :: (n2: NumberProvider) :: rest => 
    simplify(SumProvider(n1, n2) :: rest)
  case (n: NumberProvider) :: Plus :: (s: SumProvider) :: rest => 
    simplify(SumProvider(n, s) :: rest)
  case (s: SumProvider) :: Plus :: (n: NumberProvider) :: rest => 
    simplify(SumProvider(s, n) :: rest)
  case other => other // no further simplification possible
}
```

The important elements here are *case classes*, *extractors*  and *pattern matching*.

Comment: Thanks for showing me how the solution could look like. It is really tempting to change into scala. However I will try another neat approach. I will use a prolog engine and the rules will be facts in prolog :). If that doesn't work out probly I will change to Scala. Probly Can I create this functions in scala, export them into a jar and use that jar in my core?

Comment: @Tiago Scala comes with a library that, for mobile standards, is pretty huge. For a Scala application, that's just how it is, but it makes the cost of adding just a small functionality to an otherwise Java program pretty huge. Also, Scala's tooling, particularly SBT and its plugins, takes care of a lot of pains from mobile development. If you forsake it, you'll have to reproduce all that work. If you use SBT as the build tool, you'll be that much more invested in Scala.

Answer (score 0):

As a lone developer, Scala is expressive and powerful, so once mastered can be satisfying to write less and do more -- less boilerplate code, more compact idioms.

However, the power of Scala does come at a cost: it is a totally different language, with different (and I'd say more complex) idioms and syntax from Java.  Java was designed to be intentionally simple, with the idea being that in larger organizations with more code being shared among developers, explicitness and syntax simplicity are more valuable than brilliantly concise code.

Java made an intentional choice to provide a smaller toolset to make it as quick and easy as possible for one developer to pick up where another left off, so in that sense it's geared towards team development.  Scala however gives you a bit more rope to make concise but less immediately obvious constructs, which can be a minus for large enterprise environments.

Currently, Scala also has a smaller developer pool than Java, which means fewer examples and a smaller talent pool if you ever intend to hire a development team.

But as a lone developer on a solo project or in a small tight-knit team, Scala can be fun and fast to code with once you get over the significant learning hump.

Answer (score -1):

If you are switching to Scala switch to it for everything you can. There is hardly a point in using Java.

Is it worth the investment? From what one can read on the web (and my own impression) you won't become faster with Scala, but you will learn a lot.

So if you are only concerned with development speed: ignore Scala.

If you want to learn: Scala is a great choice as the next language to learn and use.

Comment: Still not sure on the status / completeness / ease of using Scala with Android, though, which would be nice.  Last time I checked it was _possible_, but I didn't know how complete it was.

Comment: However in this case I belive pattern matching would actually speed up this part. Doing something scala's pattern matching in java is tedious and boring. My classes are connected and I will have rules like: if classA connected with classB then create an classC, that can be translated in classA + classB -> classC. With pattern matching I belive that would be easy. I wanted to know for sure. Maybe I will give an example.

Comment: Scala code will be a lot shorter, but that is not where the time goes in software development. Scala is great, but its not a silver bullet.