# Pattern matching in lists that contain case classes

Tags: list, scala, pattern-matching

In the sequence of [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9891638/should-i-change-to-scala-to-create-a-system-with-rewrite-rules) I am chaging a system that allows to compose blocks to scala so I can use pattern matching to create a rewrite rule system.

However I am stuck.

I have this classes:

```
abstract class Block(n: String, in: List[Input], out: List[Out]){
  def name = n; def outputs = out; def inputs = in
}
case class GroupBlock(n: String, blocks: List[Block], in: List[Input], 
                      out: List[Out]) extends Block(n, in, out)
case class StandardBlock(n: String, in: List[Input], out: List[Out])
           extends Block(n, in, out)

abstract class Point(n: String){ def name = n }
case class Input(n:String) extends Point(n)

abstract class Out(n: String) extends Point(n)
case class Output(n:String) extends Out(n) 
case class Connection(connectedInput: Input, n: String) extends Out(n)
```

Now Imagine that I have this example without the display:

[image]

Mapped into this:

```
val inputA = Input("sumA")
val inputB = Input("sumB")
val outputB = Output("B")

val sumAB =
    GroupBlock("GroupedSum",
      StandardBlock("Sum", List(inputA, inputB), List(outputB)) :: 
      StandardBlock("Input Provider", null, Connection(inputA, "A")::Nil ) ::
      StandardBlock("Input Provider", null, Connection(inputB, "B")::Nil ) ::         
      Nil, 
      null, 
      List(outputB))
```

So... I want to be able to say: In case 2 `"Integer providers"` are connected with `"Sum"` then...

I managed to identify, with pattern matching, than a "Input Provider" exists with this:

```
sumAB match{
    case GroupBlock(_, 
          StandardBlock("Input Provider", null, _ :: Connection(input, _) :: _ ) :: _,
           _, _)
        => ...
    case GroupBlock(_,
          StandardBlock("Input Provider", null, Connection(input, _) :: _ ) :: _, 
          _, _)
        => ...
    //Covering 2 more cases where the order on the list matters
}
```

How can I say "Find me a case that has a `StandardBlock` that has the name `"Input Provider"` in the list " ? Because that is one of my main problems. I need to specify all possible combinations... Now I wanted to do something like

```
case GroupBlock(_,
          StandardBlock("Input Provider", null, Connection(input, _) ::
          StandardBlock("Sum", inputList, _  ) :: _, 
          _, _)
```

But this means "Find me a case where a "Input Provider" is in the beginning of the list and a Sum block follows that "Sum"". And I want: "Find me a case where exists a "Input Provider" exists in the same list as a "Sum".

This kind of "queries" in a list are also usefull to check if the Input Provider is Connected with the Sum block that it was found. I can use that variable `input` and ask for cases where `input` is in inputList.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9891638/should-i-change-to-scala-to-create-a-system-with-rewrite-rules/9895047 (yeah, I know it's yours -- it might help people understand what you're after)

Comment: That is why I started with "In the sequence of this topic" with a link to that :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use guards in your match clauses to help. They go like this:

`case` *pattern* `if` *guard* `=>`

where guard is an expression that can make use of the variables that have been bound in the pattern. So I think this *might* do what you want:

```
sumAB match {
  case GroupBlock(groupBlockName, blocks, _, _) if blocks.exists {
    case StandardBlock("Input Provider", _, inputProv_out) => blocks.exists { 
      case StandardBlock("Sum", sum_in, _) =>
        sum_in.exists { input =>
          inputProv_out.collect{ case Connection(connectedInput,_) =>
            connectedInput}.contains(input)
        }
      case _ =>
        false 
    }
    case _ => false
  } =>
    println("found")
  case _ =>
    println("no match")
}
```

This is an attempt as translating what you are writing *find a group block where exists an input provider where one of its `inputProv_out` output is connected to one of the sum `sum_in` inputs*.

With that said, I would be surprised if I didn't make an error. Which suggests your data structure may not be the best for what you are trying to do. Or may be you need helper functions to be able to express certain properties.

Comment: It is a really messed solution. And my example was probly one of the simplest I could find.

Should I forget case classes and try to work out with the unapply method in pattern matching? Can you suggest any changes in my structure that would simplify what I want?

Comment: @TiagoAlmeida, your diagram with Integer Provider, Sum and Display seems a lot simpler than your actual structures. Could you simplify the case classes more like your diagram?

Comment: I am not seeing a solution for that. First I need a name for every block/input/output so I can show it to user. And second I need to know the connections. Although I can do a case class for every type of block (Integer provider is a case class, Sum is a case class) I belive that will not be revolucionary... I want to simplify my structure but I am not seeing how can I do it.